# how to make this translation function code by google apps-script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I really want to add a translation menu on my google sheet but I definitely don't know what should I do at the last part.

```
function onOpen(e) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Translation')
  .addItem('ko to eng', 'myFunction')
  .addToUi();
}
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
 var trans = LanguageApp.translate(sheet,'ko','en');
```

that is it for now.
I want to make 'myFuncton' that can spread var 'trans' at the same place in the sheet.
how can I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to print the translation e.g. on cells to the right of the selected cells, you can use this function:

```js
function myFunction () {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  var trans = range.getValues().map(row => [LanguageApp.translate (row,'ko','en')])
 
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(trans)
}
```